# Implementing Custom Data Structures Using Clojure Protocols

Tags: clojure

I may have missed the whole point about protocols but my question is, can protocols be used to dictate how to iterate a custom data structure or how println would print the object?

Assuming a map with two vectors,

```
{:a [] :b []}
```

When called first on it I would like to take from the :a vector but when conj on this structure i would like to conj to :b. Can I use protocols to achieve this type of behavior?

Comment: Not yet since nearly no low-level fn (except reduce) have been "protocolized" but you can use defrecord or deftype to define a datatype that behaves like you wish.

Comment: Yes but then I have to implement the functions that act on it also, creating redundant functions names, such as head which works as first for my data structure, no?

Comment: If you use deftype, you can provide implementations for the various interfaces that Clojure uses (like clojure.lang.ISeq) that do what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some things are still implemented as Java interfaces in Clojure; of those, I'd say some are likely to stay that way forever to ease cooperating with Clojure code from other JVM languages.

Fortunately, when defining a type using `deftype`, you can have the new type implement any Java interfaces you require (which Brian mentioned in a comment above), as well as any methods of `java.lang.Object`. An example to match your description might look like this:

```
(deftype Foo [a b]
  clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection
  (seq [self] (if (seq a) self nil))
  (cons [self o] (Foo. a (conj b o)))
  (empty [self] (Foo. [] []))
  (equiv
   [self o]
   (if (instance? Foo o)
     (and (= a (.a o))
          (= b (.b o)))
     false))
  clojure.lang.ISeq
  (first [self] (first a))
  (next [self] (next a))
  (more [self] (rest a))
  Object
  (toString [self] (str "Foo of a: " a ", b: " b)))
```

A sample of what you can do with it at the REPL:

```
user> (.toString (conj (conj (Foo. [] []) 1) 2))
"Foo of a: [], b: [1 2]"
user> (.toString (conj (conj (Foo. [:a :b] [0]) 1) 2))
"Foo of a: [:a :b], b: [0 1 2]"
user> (first (conj (conj (Foo. [:a :b] [0]) 1) 2))
:a
user> (Foo. [1 2 3] [:a :b :c])
(1 2 3)
```

Note that the REPL prints it as a seq; I believe that's because of the inline implementation of `clojure.lang.ISeq`. You could skip it and replace the `seq` method with one returning `(seq a)` for a printed representation using the custom `toString`. `str` always uses `toString`, though.

If you need custom behaviour of `pr` family functions (including `println` etc.), you'll have to look into implementing a custom `print-method` for your type. `print-method` is a multimethod defined in `clojure.core`; have a look at [core_print.clj](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj) in Clojure's sources for example implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with custom collections and wanted to customise the output to the REPL so I ended up following Michal's advice on the last point. I have included the code snippet as to how to do this because I found sifting through the source took me a while as I didn't find this explained anywhere else.

```
(defmethod print-method your.custom.collection.goes.Here [c, ^java.io.Writer w]
    (.write w (str "here is my custom output: " c)))
```

This is handy, for example, in cases where the `seq` is always printing your custom vector with parentheses (as with Michal's example) and you want square brackets like regular Clojure vectors:

```
(defmethod print-method your.custom.Vector [v, ^java.io.Writer w]
    (.write w (str (into [] v))))
```

It also means the way can now implement `seq` to actually return a sequence of your data type rather than just having to implement it for REPL output.